# Crear url para GET en Java SpringBoot - Sonar

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un servicio web hecho con SpringBoot que recibe muchos parámetros:

```
https://localhost:8080/pruebaClientes?compania=1&lugar=2&tal=pascual
```

Y así hasta 15 claves.

Desde la parte del cliente que también es un Java se crea la url formándola de la siguiente manera para llamar al servicio web:

Ejemplo para que se entienda:

```
String url = baseURL.toString();
boolean primero = false;

if(compania != null and !"".equals(compania)){
 primero = true;
 url = url + "?compania=" + compania;
}

if(lugar...){

if(!primero){
url = url + "&lugar=" + lugar;
}else {
 primero = true;
url = url + "?lugar=" + lugar;
}

}
```

etc

Como se puede ver, voy con una boolean para saber cuando es la primera vez para poner un ? y después creo la url en formato String (El RestTemplate acepta String)

**El problema es que tengo un error de Sonar porque al tener muchos ifs y dentro de esos if, más ifs, dice que la 'complejidad es muy alta'.**

Lo único que se me ocurre es crearme 20 funciones y que devuelvan 1 parte de url cada una de ellas para que no salte el sonar, pero lo veo una chapuza, ¿hay alguna solución mejor y más limpia para crear una url (El RestTemplate acepta String)?
Gracias.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que estás reinventando la rueda en vez de usar herramientas ya existentes..., por ejemplo: [UriBuilder.queryParams()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilder.html#queryParams(org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap)). La documentación está para usarla. Y bendito sonar, que no deja pasar este tipo de cosas. Lo que estás intentando hacer es mil veces más complejo de mantener de lo necesario, con lo fácil que es crear un mapa. Y mucho más fácil de mantener que tener que mirar 30 ifs!

Comment: Gracias, era con eso, no sabía que existía.